# How to emulate gps location in Android-x86 simulator(VirtualBox)?

Tags: android, maps, android-x86

I want to get longitude and latitude in android Simulator(ported in Android x86)for testing.

Can any one guide me how to achieve this?

How do I set the location of the emulator to a test position?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use "[Fake GPS location](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps)" application from Google play for emulating GPS location.

Comment: Does it simulate unreliability/random errors of GPS?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to at this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html

under **Setting the location of the phone**

Or here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html#MockData